# How To Serve Spring-Rest Response To JSP View

Tags: jsp, spring-rest

*Hi, I don't know  this right question or not but i got doubt thats why i posted this question.*

if i use @RestController then i can write my response directly to HTTP Response object.  But, i want to serve that response to JSP. how to serve this response to JSP? please , help me on this, i searched and read so many blogs and websites still i didn't get any clarification. #inSTACKOVERFLOW    [How to use Spring 4 Rest Controller to serve for Jsp view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987062/how-to-use-spring-4-rest-controller-to-serve-for-jsp-view) I got this one, but here 
Same question asked by some one, here they are suggested  like instead of @RestController use @Controller for JSP View.

**@Controller:** This Annotation introduced in Spring2.5 Version. For Supporting WEB-Services, the spring people used @ResponseBody with @Controller , if You Use  @ResponseBody Then you can write response directly into Http Response. Later

**@RestController:** This Annotation introduced in Spring4.0 Version, Instead of using @Controller+@ResponseBody simple you can use @RestController.

so, finally with help of @RestController we can write response directly into HTTP Response Object. This Response, i want to send to JSP View.

i know,  by using ajax we can do it. but if i use ajax i can get every response into same page only.

Here , if i want to use JSP's for View with the combination of Spring-Rest, 
how can i pass my response to jsp view.

Please help me.

Comment: ResponseBody is not for jsp pages. it is used for json as example . So thats why RestController is not used for jsp pages, too. Use Controller and insert the data you need into you model

Comment: Thanks for Reply, After this discussion i came to know . Yes , you are right  `Http Response Object is not for jsp pages`. to get response from Controller to jsp we need to use model object with @Controller annotation.  for like JSON Response or XML Response we can use RestController( spring-rest).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it the way as Quissal said.

With a rest controller, your return type is normaly some kind of object for serialisation (like into json) and NOT a jsp page

To do a web application you have to use @controller and a jsp mapping.

There a lot of examples on the web, like:
http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example-annotation/

Comment: Thanks for Reply,  after your reply i got to know @Controller for developing web-applications. RestController for developing web-services concept for communicating different platfrom applications.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use a RestController to return a jsp page, change your annotation into @Controller and make your functions return a jsp page.

If you need to offer a Rest service and return a jsp as well then refer to  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50470457/5720436)

Answer (score 0):

Use @Controller annotation, and set data in ModelMap and return String (should be jsp name)

**Controller**:-

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/product")
public class ProductController {

   @RequestMapping(method == RequestMethod.GET)
   public String getProduct(ModelMap model) {

       //get details from db and set to modelmap, testing hardcoded product name
      model.addAttribute("productName", "toys");
      return "productDetails";  
   }
```

Jsp page to access model data as,

**productDetails.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
  <body>
     <h2>${productName}</h2>
  </body>
</head>
</html>
```