# How do I render a Spring view(JSP) in a <div> tag after submit a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, jsp

I'm using Spring MVC for my application. I have a form for receiving start date and end date from daterangepicker. And I want to display another view, that has a table after querying, into the "dataDiv" below the form after submitting the form, but not reload the page. 
What I've done so far, the result is when I submitted a form, it redirected to new page (request-data.jsp) but the table worked fine.

Here are my code...

**JSP**

```html
<form action="view-data" method="get" id="ajaxTest">
  <div id="reportrange" class="form-control">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> 
    <span></span>
    <b class="caret"></b>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="startDate" name="startDate" /> 
  <input type="hidden" id="endDate" name="endDate" /> 
  <input type="submit" value="VIEW" id="ajaxBtn" />
</form>
<div id="dataDiv"></div>
```

**Javascript** I used Ajax for loading another view.

```js
$('#ajaxTest').submit(function(event) {
  var startDate = $('#reportrange').data('daterangepicker').startDate;
  var endDate = $('#reportrange').data('daterangepicker').endDate;
  document.getElementById("startDate").value = startDate;
  document.getElementById("endDate").value = endDate;
  $.ajax({
    url : "../request-data",
    type : 'GET',
    data : data,
    success : function(response) {
      alert("success"); 
      $('#dataDiv').html( response );
    },
    error : function() {
      alert("error");
    }
  });
return false;
});
```

**Spring Controller**

```js
@RequestMapping(value = "/request-data", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView requestRanking(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, @RequestParam("startDate") Date stDate, @RequestParam("endDate") Date edDate, RedirectAttributes rd) {
  ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
      /*
      *Query for book created between stDate and edDate
      */
  rd.addFlashAttribute("bookForms", bookForms);
  mav.setViewName("request-data");
  return mav;
}
```

And in **request-data.jsp** view

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.footable').footable();
  });
```

```html
<div>
  <c:if test="${!empty bookForms}">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm m-b-xs" id="filter" placeholder="Search in table" />
    <table id="page-size-example" class="footable table table-stripped" data-page-size="" data-filter=#filter data-sorting="true">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th data-type="numeric" data-sort-initial="true">#</th>
          <th>BOOKNAME</th>
          <th>PRICE</th>
          <th>CREATED_DATE</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${bookForms}" var="bookForm" varStatus="status">
          <tr>
            <td>${status.count}</td>
            <td>${bookForm.name}</td>
            <td>${bookForm.price}</td>
            <td>${bookForm.createdDate}</td>
          </tr>
        </c:forEach>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </c:if>
</div>
```

Is there any other way to do this? Please help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for you [how to use spring4 @RestController to return a jsp page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26031254/how-to-use-spring4-restcontroller-to-return-a-jsp-page)
You should add a `@ResponseBody` annotation to your method or `@RestController` to your class if every method works with ajax. This annotations make your controllers/methods to work async with ajax.

Some code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/request-data", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView requestRanking(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, @RequestParam("startDate") Date stDate, @RequestParam("endDate") Date edDate, RedirectAttributes rd) {
   ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
   mav.setViewName("request-data");
   //your actions
   return mav;
}
```

Comment: I've tried that one before, but it doesn't work, the result's still the same. Thanks